# Configuring JD-Eclipse Java Decompiler plugin for Eclipse Java EE IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, decompiler, jd-eclipse

I installed JD-Eclipse to the exact specifications of the directions [here](http://jd.benow.ca/). Now when I navigate to a .class file via File > Open, I receive this error:

The Class File Viewer cannot handle the given input ('org.eclipse.ui.ide.FileStoreEditorInput').

Do I have to configure the plugin, or do I need to add the .class file to a project repository or something like that?

Comment: Follow the link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45995421/3454208

Answer (score 0):

`FileStoreEditorInput` is used when a file is not in the workspace. It looks like jd-eclipse can only open files which are in your Eclipse workspace.